# Download image from HTTPS and upload to firebase storage in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, https

I need to upload the thumbnails of my files from the web to firebase storage. The URL is always like

**https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?authuser=0&sz=w320&id=1086hD9ShV98klN4n3o187V_DdNTzXsiZyPn20nUHBM4**

with the HTTPS and I'm having a lot of trouble doing this

In order to upload to firebase storage, I can use a bitmap, inputStream, URL, or a local File

I have tried with many different libraries, Picasso, glide,... but I always get the same error of file not found. From what I read here, I think it is because it is an HTTPS

How can I do this?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I tried using the glide library as sugested, but didnt work with all urls, this is my code:

```
// the thmbnail link is combined with the fileId
        String thumbnailLink = "https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?authuser=0&sz=w320&id=" + databasePost.getFileId();
        Log.i("SecondActivity", "thumbnailLink: "+ thumbnailLink );

        String thumbnailId = databasePost.getFileId() + ".png";

        Glide.with(this)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(thumbnailLink)
                .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap image, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                        Log.i("SecondActivity", "loadBitmap: resource ready " );

                        String thumbnailId = databasePost.getFileId() + ".png";

                        StorageReference postRef = storage.child("thumbnails").child(thumbnailId);

                        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                        byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

                        UploadTask uploadTask = postRef.putBytes(data);
                        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                Log.i("SecondActivity", "saveThumbnailToStorage: success");
                                databasePost.setThumbnailId(thumbnailId);
                              //  saveDataToDatabase(databasePost);
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.i("SecondActivity", "saveThumbnailToStorage: error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadFailed(@Nullable Drawable errorDrawable) {
                        super.onLoadFailed(errorDrawable);
                        Log.i("SecondActivity", "loadBitmap: error: " + errorDrawable);

                    }
                });
```

This is the error I get:

```
    2021-01-22 17:24:39.500 8486-8486/com.curso.testebottomnavigationviewdriveapi W/Glide: Load failed for https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?authuser=0&sz=w320&id=14fwtU1NKPaeuSmagklCHRLJwxRCnSgjial7MoySK2-k with size [-2147483648x-2147483648]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/14fwtU1NKPaeuSmagklCHRLJwxRCnSgjial7MoySK2-k=w320)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/14fwtU1NKPaeuSmagklCHRLJwxRCnSgjial7MoySK2-k=w320)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/14fwtU1NKPaeuSmagklCHRLJwxRCnSgjial7MoySK2-k=w320)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/14fwtU1NKPaeuSmagklCHRLJwxRCnSgjial7MoySK2-k=w320
2021-01-22 17:24:39.501 8486-8486/com.curso.testebottomnavigationviewdriveapi I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 1)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/14fwtU1NKPaeuSmagklCHRLJwxRCnSgjial7MoySK2-k=w320
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:259)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:211)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:102)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:118)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:56)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.startNextOrFail(MultiModelLoader.java:164)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.onLoadFailed(MultiModelLoader.java:154)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:62)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:70)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:279)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:393)
2021-01-22 17:24:39.501 8486-8486/com.curso.testebottomnavigationviewdriveapi I/SecondActivity: loadBitmap: error: null
```

EDIT 2:
I tried adding android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

this is the network security:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
<domain includeSubdomains="true">drive.google.com</domain>
 </ domain-config>
 </network-security-config>
```

I have android 10 and glide version 4.11

Comment: "I always get the same error of file not found" Can you show the [minimal code that reproduces the problem that you're asking for our help on](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? That makes it much more likely that someone can help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I tried with Glide library as sugested and updated the question with the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally discovered what was causing this error!
So basically I was trying to upload the thumbnail right after uploading the file but if I did the exact same but some time after uploading it worked fine.

Apparently you have to wait sometime after uplaoding so that the link t the thumbnail is valid so now I'm using the exact same code to upload with glide but before using it I wait 10 seconds and it works perfectly!

```
     try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);

   String thumbnailLink = "https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?authuser=0&sz=w320&id=" + databasePost.getFileId();
        Log.i("SecondActivity", "thumbnailLink: "+ thumbnailLink );

        String thumbnailId = databasePost.getFileId() + ".png";

        Glide.with(this)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(thumbnailLink)
                .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap image, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                        Log.i("SecondActivity", "loadBitmap: resource ready " );

                        String thumbnailId = databasePost.getFileId() + ".png";

                        StorageReference postRef = storage.child("thumbnails").child(thumbnailId);

                        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                        byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

                        UploadTask uploadTask = postRef.putBytes(data);
                        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                Log.i("SecondActivity", "saveThumbnailToStorage: success");
                                databasePost.setThumbnailId(thumbnailId);
                              //  saveDataToDatabase(databasePost);
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.i("SecondActivity", "saveThumbnailToStorage: error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadFailed(@Nullable Drawable errorDrawable) {
                        super.onLoadFailed(errorDrawable);
                        Log.i("SecondActivity", "loadBitmap: error: " + errorDrawable);

                    }
                });

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.i("UploadPostActivity", "failure sleep: "+e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly first of all you have a problem loading the image. I'm not sure that the url you specified can be loaded without API (it is not possible to open it in the browser for me)

Have you tried any other image/url?

Check in the log where the error is...

You can load bitmap with Glide (working code):

```
private void loadBitmapByGlide(String imageUrl, String imageName) {
        Glide.with(this)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(imageUrl)
                .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap image, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                        //TODO upload image to firebase storage or something else
                        //String imagePath = savePNG(resource, imageName);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image loaded: " + image.getWidth() + "-" + image.getHeight(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

                    }
                });
    }
```

gradle file

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
```

Comment: You can try with android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in Manifest or with network_security_config (search for more details) if you use android 9. Also try with another android version or phone

Comment: I just checked one more time for both links and it works fine, glide version 4.11.0 and compileSdkVersion 30, android 6 and 11

Comment: I just uploaded the question with what I did after searching about network_security_config, what did you do to be able to get them? I have android 10

Comment: I used posted method (above) in one my app with your links...

Comment: Also you told "didnt work with all urls" for you, check differences and try them in browser, also try with another phone/emulator or android version. Did you try with android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"?

Comment: All the urls are the same, only the fileId changes and I can open all of them in my browser. I uploaded the question with what I added in networkSecurityConfig you can see after EDIT2 but I'm not sure if this is how I should use it because it still doesn't work out. Also, I'll try in my emulator to see if it works

Comment: I see now... you probably suggested edit for my answer by mistake with the same, please remove it... I'm really sorry but I have no idea what is the reason that works for me and not for you...try skipMemoryCache(true) method for glide, or change internet connection, phone, rebuild project, reinstall app, invalidate cashes... sometimes very strange reasons can happen that the code does not work (by experience)

Comment: Hi! I tried everything you said but still nothing works I'm getting this error: **Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored** Do you know what it can be?

Comment: I searched it up and created the MyAppGlideModule to use GlideApp instead of only Glide, and this error isn't showing up anymore, but I still get the error: **caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:** Are you using AndroidX? Is it possible for you to send me your project for me to see what  I'm missing?

Comment: Yes, I use AndroidX...I checked this more time to get same error but it works fine... Do you use OkHttp library? Also I can not share my project its so complicated... you can create new one and simulate code that you need (only for loading image) and share git here

Comment: Oh! Allright, no problems. No I'm not using  OkHttp Library, should I be using it? How can I do it?

Comment: Glide uses it so I thought there is a conflict if you use it....  but no

Comment: I really don't want to give you the wrong instructions so I created a new app added the method above in main activity and glide into the gradle(as above) and it works again... when its loaded imageview is updated with imageView.setImageBitmap(image); Also I loaded it with skipMemoryCache(true) and no cashing **If you want try this don't forget add internet permission

Comment: HI! I tested in a new project and it worked perfetly! Do you have any ideas of what might be the error?

Comment: No, I have no idea hahah... I am very curious about this... Did you try invalidate cashes, clear project or rebuild project... if you need help to do this feel free to comment here... if you did, can you post somewhere module gradle or manifest BUT Please, just make sure you don't have any sensitive data in both like singing config, ads, firebase or other ids...be careful...

Comment: I just accidentally clicked on the test application and the image did not load... I checked logcat and got class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource... Also I checked url in browser and got 403. That’s an error. 
Your client does not have permission to get URL...[This image URL](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/1086hD9ShV98klN4n3o187V_DdNTzXsiZyPn20nUHBM4=w320?authuser=0)

Comment: Hi, yeah, I did all of these things, invalidate cache, rebuild, clean, restart, but still it didnt worked in that project. This link really shouldn't work anymore, because I deleted the file as it was just a test but forgot about the stackOverflow question, my bad... it probably belongs to a new file or to something else now. But this one:  

https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?authuser=0&sz=w320&id=1HHNdVFfGSnLLXsvpN5ITEktsdNENLT-jYl1guyNqgZw
should work

Comment: I can't really post all my code because there are a lot of other things but these are the implementations I'm using: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BDsB2mXw9a0nV9jnvm161msKebiZcJ4EVWOiPsVtleI/edit 
There are a lot of ependencies as it was a test, I think something is conflicting with glide library

Comment: What context do you use for glide? I can't guess by code...

Comment: getAplicaionContext() or this, but I think it can't be the context, because It worked with one file

Comment: In case you were wondering, apparently the error happens because the link isn't usable yet, so I have to wait sometime after the file creation to be ablle to access the thumbnailLink

Comment: Wow we spent a lot of time, I'm glad you solved it. I upvoted your answer above but Im not sure TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep (10) is a good way to wait it (Its same Thread.sleep). If it's on the UI (I believe it isn't) use Handle.postDelayed()...